# Greetings/wishes after salatul jummah

Tags: salat, practical-islam, jumuah

I am pretty new to Islam and I am not an arabic speaker either. In my mosque I noticed people greet each other after salatul jummah with different greetings/wishes. One that was offered to me was "Taqwallah".

Is it possible for you to list a few other greetings/wishes that can be used after salatul jummah and in general? If possible, please also attach the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

What people have wished for you, is that Allah may accept your prayer (in this case), they've said "taqaballa Allah تقبل الله" which literally means: May Allah accept ... .

This basically isn't bad, but maybe some people may say it is not sunnah or even declare it as bid'ah. On the whole it is pretty usual.

Some may also say: jumu'ah mubaraka جمعة مباركة meaning blessed Friday.